# Which logic gate most correctly identifies with the following c# statement?

Tags: c#, boolean-logic

I was just playing with a console application generating logic truth table and hit on the following c# statement

```
bool a, b, c; //get inputs
if(a = b = c)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("sucess"); // print if 1
    }
```

The statement `if(a = b = c)` returns true only if `bool c` is true(edit: my expectation was that all inputs need to be same for sucess). Can someone explain how this statement is executing?

Edit: I saw IV4s answer which was 
 `if( a== b == c )` out of curiosity i compiled it and it works.
Edit2: Henk is right.  a=false,b=true,c=false returns true.

Comment: `=` is the **assignment** operator, not a logical operator.

Comment: c is assigned to b and then to a.

Comment: This won't even compile since you didn't initialize `c` variable.

Comment: @SonerGönül dont you read `//get inputs` its called magic code you just have to think and its initialized :P

Comment: Re the deleted answer:  Yes, `if(a == b == c)` is evaluated as `if( (a == b) == c )` and that works for booleans. But it will return `true` for example when a=false,b=true,c=false .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is the assigment operator, it's not the same as `==` (the comparison operator). Which means that in case of `a = b = c` statment it assigns value of `c` to `b` and then to `a`, which is later evaluated by `if`.

It's evaluated like this:

```
b = c;
a = b;
if (a) { }
```

If you want to make sure all variables are equal then you need to do this:

```
// no need to check if a == c
if (a == b && b == c) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As @I4V said in your `IF` you are assigning the value of c to B and then A. Hence it is always evaluating to **`true`** as you are not doing any logical operation.

`=` is assignment and `==` is used for logical operation.